# Connect to JMS from JSP

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to connect to **ActiveMQ** using **JSP**. However, when i run the program, it gives me an exception of the type:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Destination .
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I have included the **activeMQ jar** file in the build path.

Any help on this is appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit:** Do I have to include anything in web.xml for the libraries to work? The error is actually from a class in the jar file and not from something i have coded. So I am really confused. I tried changing the jar file and included a newly downloaded one. But that didn't help.

Comment: Which java command do you use to start the program?

Comment: Hi, I use Eclipse to run my program so i don't use any commands.

Comment: Hi, have you added activemq-<version>.jar and spring-1.x.jar to your classpath?

Comment: I have added the activemq jar file but im not aware of the spring jar. Could you please let me know what exactly this would do? Thanks

Comment: look [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/109773-how-to-add-all-relevant-spring-jars-to-a-classpath-in-a-modular-way) and [here](https://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html).

Comment: I tried adding the spring framework to the build path. It still din't work. Is there any other way we can solve this? Any jar i add is not amking a difference and im still getting a NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: The JSP file is run from a server, like Tomcat or Glassfish.  The 3rd party dependencies should be in the WEB-INF\lib folder.  Are you starting a server within Eclipse or outside Eclipse.  Otherwise, not sure how you are running your JSP file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have dependencies to ActiveMQ installed - you simply need the JMS interface.

Add the [geronimo jms specs](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1), that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But no matter what jar files i add to the build path and import them in my code, jms libraries are not being included at runtime. I still get a NoClassDefFoundError. Could you please help?

Comment: It depends a lot on *how* you are running your JSP app. Is it a web app using spring on tomcat? is it something else? Are you using JNDI or plain code to handle config? It seems you are not including the jar in the correct way